# Date format jquery and localization

Tags: jquery

How to set dd/mm/yy on departureDate input field. But i'm thinking to change both format to be Indonesian localization like "Senin 05 Agustus 2015".

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/JKGvD/658/)

```
Arrive:
<input type="text" id="arrivalDate" class="datepicker">
<br />Nights:
<input type="text" id="numOfNights" value="1">
<br />Depart:
<input type="text" id="departureDate">
```

jquery script

```
$('#arrivalDate').datepicker({

    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: function (dateStr) {
        var nights = parseInt($('#numOfNights').val());
        var depart = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);
        depart.setDate(depart.getDate() + nights);
        $('#departureDate').val(depart);
    }
});

$('#numOfNights').change(function () {
    var nights = parseInt($('#numOfNights').val());
    var depart = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $('#arrivalDate').val());
    depart.setDate(depart.getDate() + nights);
    $('#departureDate').val(depart);
});
```

Comment: You can take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/3863146), and you can also use this [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for getting localised time.

Comment: @Sahil well then, how to set departuredate to same value as arrivalDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) like this:

```
    moment.locale('id'); //'id'--> Bahasa Indonesia
    $('#arrivalDate').datepicker({

        dateFormat: "d/MM/yy",
        onSelect: function (dateStr) {
            var nights = parseInt($('#numOfNights').val());
            var depart = $.datepicker.parseDate('d/MM/yy', dateStr);
            depart.setDate(depart.getDate() + nights);
            var depart_date = moment(depart).format('DD/MMMM/YYYY');
            console.log('date is '+depart_date);
            $('#departureDate').val(depart_date);
        }
    });

    $('#numOfNights').change(function () {
        var nights = parseInt($('#numOfNights').val());
        var depart = $.datepicker.parseDate('d/MM/yy', $('#arrivalDate').val());
        depart.setDate(depart.getDate() + nights);
         var depart_date = moment(depart).format('DD/MMMM/YYYY');
        $('#departureDate').val(depart_date);
    });
```

Demo available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JKGvD/659/).

**Edited**

Adding one more option using **jQuery datepicker** itself. Just put this localization CDN after **jquery-ui.js**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
```

And then change the code like this:

```
//setting the default locale to Indonesian
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["id"]);
    $('#arrivalDate').datepicker({

            dateFormat: "d/MM/yy",

            onSelect: function (dateStr) {
                var nights = parseInt($('#numOfNights').val());
                var depart = $.datepicker.parseDate('d/MM/yy', dateStr);
                depart.setDate(depart.getDate() + nights);
                $('#departureDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('d/MM/yy', depart));
            }
        });

        $('#numOfNights').change(function () {
            var nights = parseInt($('#numOfNights').val());
            var depart = $.datepicker.parseDate('d/MM/yy',        $('#arrivalDate').val());
            depart.setDate(depart.getDate() + nights); 
             $('#departureDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('d/MM/yy', depart));
        });
    $(function() {
            $( "#departureDate" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "d/MM/yy"});
        });
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JKGvD/661/).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. but last i was add $(function() {$( "#departureDate" ).datepicker();}); after #numOfNights script. The problem is, departureDate doesnt highlight current date of input field. Any idea?

Comment: **#departureDate** doesnt highlight current date of which input field?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JKGvD/660/ the depart field doesnt highlight, if you select date on arrive field you will see orange color highlighting the date you choose. But not on depart field

Comment: @Harriz, please check the updated answer. You can just add the localization CDN available for jquery datepicker.